# What is my landlord's second job?

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

My landlord is a little eccentric. Every time he visits my flat for inspection, he places a seed in the kitchen just before he leaves.

What is my landlord's second job?

> Hint: He is a father of 4.

> Hint: The answer has nothing to do with plants.

> Hint: Changing the second sentence to past tense may help.

> Hint: As long as the seed is in my flat, where my landlord places it is irrelevant.

Comment: if you can hint , do he do this act openly or just when no one is looking

Comment: may be he work at pest control

Comment: kitchen seeder︁

Comment: Does the question contain a hint?

Comment: @Deepthinker101 No, “second job” isn’t a hint as being a landlord is already a job

Comment: I thought it might have had a double meaning

Comment: Are the number of sentences important?

Comment: @Deepthinker101 No.

Comment: Are there any anagrams?

Comment: @Deepthinker101 There’s no point to the puzzle if you keep on asking questions.

Comment: Could he be a doctor or something , he has 4 children thats a lot , he places a  wild carrot seed which is a birth control  ┐( ∵ )┌

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds possible he's a

> Lieutenant colonel. In the UK this is pronounced 'leftenant kernel', and he left you a seed (kernel).

Some hint explanations:

> He is a father of 4 - the NATO officer rank **[OF-4](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/OF-4)** is a lieutenant colonel in the UK.
>  The answer is not to do with plants and changing the clue to past tense  - he *left* the seed.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually 2 questions.  1. For what reason should someone leave a seed in the kitchen.  2. What does it tell about the landlord's second job.

I can see two reasons for the seed:

1. There is a mouse in the house.  The landlord likes animals so he leaves a nut for the mouse to eat.
2. The seed is just there to check whether the tenant is cleaning the place.
   The landlord takes hygiene seriously.  If the seed is still there next time he comes, the landlord has a motive to kick the tenant out.

So what is the job of the landlord?
For 1. I would venture the landlord has to do with animals, a vet or has an animal shop.  For 2. I could imagine he is in the cleaning business. Housekeeping.

But since there is a tag "wordplay", I want to combine these answers and say he is a

> Mousekeeper.

Comment: Nope, but you are the closest yet (though the answer itself is still as far away as the other ones). There is one word in your post that links very close to the answer.

Comment: Anyway, It doesn explain the hint, (father of 4).

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe he is a spiritualist or some plant nutritionist.
> The plant could be a clover plant with four leaves. considering it a wordplay the 'he' >!leaves is for plant leaves which has 4 children might represent four leaves plant, mostly clover, placing a seed in hope more clover grows with 4 leaves. The person must be a something like a priest who considers the 4 leaves clover precious or some plant lover

> down votes are appreciated so are up vote and so are no vote (=^▽^=)

> also maybe his second job is renting house , Just kidding

Comment: I like your train of thought but in fact the answer has nothing to do with plants

Answer (score -2):

> he imports (or possibly grows) coconuts.

because

> Coconuts are the seed of the coconut palm, and seem like an apropriate gift to leave in a kitchen.